# AngularJS ng-options not populating from Promise values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have a select box which bind the data from the database.

```
<div class="select__wrapper-inner" data-ng-init="loadCountries()">
   <select id="country" ng-model="selectedCountry"
           ng-options="country.CountryName for country in countries">
      <option value="" selected>Select your option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Below is the loadCountries function

```
$scope.loadCountries = function () {       
    var resultList = mainService.loadCountries();
    resultList.then(function (response) {          
        $scope.countries = response.data;  
        $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries[0];
    });       
}
```

Also here is the loadcountires code in service

```
function mainService($http) {
    this.loadCountries = function () {
        var result = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/API/Country/Countries'               
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I checked countries list, it is populating succesfully, but not binding to ng-options in the select box.
Can anyone help me with this please !!

Comment: can you write also the `mainStallionService.loadCountries()` method and how looks the response?

Comment: @Davebra that code section has been added now

Answer (score 0):

Change ng-options like this and try.

```
<div class="select__wrapper-inner" data-ng-init="loadCountries()">
   <select id="country" ng-model="selectedCountry"
           ng-options="country as country.CountryName for country in countries">
      <option value="" selected>Select your option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: still the same, select box not getting any value.

Comment: does web service getting called?

Comment: Yes, I can see the countries list in $scope variable, but select box not getting the values.

Comment: ok then $scope.loadCountries() call inside controller instead of data-ng-init="loadCountries()" and try.

Comment: Also, declare  $scope.countries = []; in controller.

Comment: it is very strange now, it loads for first time, then when I refresh the page, it clears all the values from select box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205290/discussion-between-sjpadikkoth-and-ashish-bakwad).